# Are long regular expressions worse than short ones?

Tags: regex, python-3.x, regex-group

I was trying to learn about regular expressions for a project where I want to create a [textmate grammar](https://macromates.com/manual/en/language_grammars), regexes seem relatively simple but really hard to read for me, so I tried to create a utility module hat could generate them, it kinda works as intended and generate regular expressions that actually work, all aliased by easy to understand names.

for example:

```py
struc_enum = OrGroup("struct", "enum")
whitespace = TAB_SPACE.at_least(1)
```

results in:

```regex
(?:struct|enum)
[ \t]+
```

in this case, there's not much benefit in using python aliases but then I can do:

```
valid_name = r"\b" + Group(ALPHA, ALPHANUMERIC.repeated())
struc_enum = OrGroup("struct", "enum")
typed_name = (struc_enum + whitespace).optional() + valid_name + whitespace + valid_name.captured()
```

and ths is what `print(typed_name)` displays:

```
(?:(?:(?:struct|enum)[ \t]+)?\b[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\d]*[ \t]+(\b[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\d]*))
```

This method can be used to create small snippets and concatenate them to construct more complex patterns, but for each level of concatenation the expression grows exponentially large, such that I could easily get at this point:

```
(?:(func)[\s]+([a-zA-Z_]+[a-zA-Z\d_]*)[\s]*\([\s]*(?:[a-zA-Z_]+[a-zA-Z\d_]*(?:[\s]*[a-zA-Z_]+[a-zA-Z\d_]*[*]{,2})?(?:[\s]*,[\s]*[a-zA-Z_]+[a-zA-Z\d_]*(?:[\s]*[a-zA-Z_]+[a-zA-Z\d_]*[*]{,2})?)*[\s]*)?\))
```

In an atom grammar this big regex above can match lines like this, but it doesn't seem to work elsewhere:

```
func myfunc(asd asd*, asd*, asdasd)
func do_foo01(type arg1, int arg2)
```

With enough patience, a human might construct an equivalent expression but probably much shorter, which raises the question. Are big regular expressions worse or better than the equivalent shorter ones int terms of computational overhead? At which point can we consider regexes too big?

Comment: Computational complexity is mostly independent of pattern length. I wouldn't worry 
much about performance unless you've actually run a performance test and have identified that a particular section of code is indeed taking up a disproportionate amount of resources. If you're sure that a particular generated RE is correct, and that its logic is sufficiently understandable, that's probably enough, regardless of how long the pattern ultimately ends up being

Comment: Welcome to SO! Agreed completely with CP, but I think it's worth mentioning that this sort of "autogenerated" approach could lead to [catastrophic backtracking](https://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html) situations and other difficult-to-reason-about issues, not to mention: are they verifiable and accurate? When a bug arises, how hard will it be to resolve? Surely there is a better approach to solving this problem, and even short regexes can be terribly inefficient.

Comment: After doing a few tests, the logic seems to hold mostly WYSIWYG without major problems, but I'm new at this and could be wrong, I got catastrophic backtracking once but It was easy to spot and fix by reordering individual pieces of the expression and testing it on a service like [regexr](https://regexr.com/) until it worked, I was worried about performance because, well, generally more code takes more time to compute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a fine idea, but you need to be clear with yourself about the scale of the project you're undertaking.

We almost never *need* to use regular expressions; we could take apart every string and write our own parsing operations using `starts_with` and `if`s etc. But regex syntax is a **mature**, **powerful** system that let's us **succinctly** express certain kinds of logic.

Often regexes are hard to read. There are [some tools](https://regex101.com/) that can help, but the idea of a **less succinct** system for doing the stuff we currently do with regexs is sound. The hard part will be replicating the **breadth**, **power**, and **reliability** of existing regex systems.

My guess is you'll be best served by learning to tolerate the density of regular expressions. Possibly *we* might be better served by you building a easier-to-read system for sting-parsing, but you'll have about 20 years of catching up to do.

**Regarding performance:** Regexes are (can be) compiled. Depending on the context, this can have a big performance benefit.
Anyway, like any sufficiently powerful language, the length of the instruction is a poor indicator of it's run-time complexity.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, so performance is not very linked ti length in this case.
For this project I can only use RE or tree-sitter because a [textmate/atom grammar](https://github.com/atom/language-python/blob/master/grammars/python.cson) is just a .json file encapsulating lots and lots of REs and [tree-sitter](http://tree-sitter.github.io/tree-sitter/creating-parsers) is way beyond my current skill level and niche language I also don't have to worry with creating a whole new system, at the end its just string concatenation.

Answer (score 1):

Since the original problem you set out to solve is that long regular expressions are difficult to read, you may wish to consider extended (verbose) regular expressions.  Extended regular expressions allow whitespace and comments, which can make a regular expression much easier to read.

Contrast this regular expression:

```
charref = re.compile("&#(0[0-7]+"
                     "|[0-9]+"
                     "|x[0-9a-fA-F]+);")
```

with the same regular expression, with comments:

```
charref = re.compile(r"""
 &[#]                # Start of a numeric entity reference
 (
     0[0-7]+         # Octal form
   | [0-9]+          # Decimal form
   | x[0-9a-fA-F]+   # Hexadecimal form
 )
 ;                   # Trailing semicolon
""", re.VERBOSE)
```

Example taken from [Regular Expression HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html)

Comment: Thanks, that's good to know but I was not only trying to make the expressions more readable, for this specific project, following [this guide](https://gist.github.com/Aerijo/b8c82d647db783187804e86fa0a604a1), I found myself copying and pasting so much that it made sense to save pieces of expressions under variables, then containers.